# Ruby On Rails - How to pass params through a custom before_validation function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parameters, model, rails-activestorage

I have a function that needs params passed. The function is:

```rb
private

def file_type(file)
 # code content
end
```

I am trying to access the code from the same model file using these methods:

```rb
has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
has_one_attached :image1, dependent: :destroy

before_validation :file_type, file: :image
before_validation :file_type, file: :image1

before_validation :file_type(params[:image])
before_validation :file_type(params[:image1])
```

And a few others but non of them work.
Is there a way to pass in the params without having to create a new validation class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method in your class that passes the parameters.

```
before_validation :file_types

def file_types
  file_type(image)
  file_type(image1)
end
```